How to use MTA in MFC DLLs?
We are developing an asp.net app to call an unmanaged DLL created via MFC/Visual C++ 2008. The DLL will use Excel Automation, so it will call OleInitialize() to initialize the COM library.
The developer said the DLL must be set to multithreaded apartment(MTA) to work, otherwise it will hand and timeout. However, in this document , it said MFC DLL must be in STA mode. So is there a workaround for this case?

COM apartments relate to threads, not modules. If you need to call into an interface whose threading requirements differ from the calling thread's apartment you need to create a new thread, initialize the apartment, and make your call from there.

@IInspectable, In that case, if the MDF DLL codes are used to create the new thread, and initialize to MFA, will that be any problems?

I don't understand the question. Have a look at Processes, Threads, and Apartments for an introduction to COM's threading architecture. That should help you understand the problem better.

There are a lot of mine fields here.

Office applications should not be invoked via your ASP.NET application.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2#:~:text=Microsoft%20does%20not%20currently%20recommend%2C%20and%20does%20not,deadlock%20when%20Office%20is%20run%20in%20this%20environment.

You are using a very out of support version of VC++ and MFC, and likely creating a security hazard if this site.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/visual-studio-2008

MFC is not compatible with MTAs as it leverages thread specific handle maps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn003-mapping-of-windows-handles-to-objects?view=msvc-170

I don't know what happened to 3., but could you explain how 4. could ever be true? What fundamental rules of the universe need to change for that not to be false anymore?

Misnumbered the list apparently. If you try to use MFC to implement a COM object that supports MultiThreaded Apartments, that code can be invoked on any thread (not just the UI thread). Many MFC classes wrap handles (like HWND) which have thread affinity, as described in that TechNote. So, you really want to avoid MFC when implementing MTA/COM objects.

That's the wrong conclusion. The correct conclusion is to avoid using USER/GDI objects that have thread affinity from multiple threads. Barring that you at least need to know the thread affinity rules of objects.

MFC is a legacy framework designed for building GUI based applications with support for OLE/COM tacked on over the years. ATL on the other hand is a legacy framework that was specifically designed for coding COM objects (STA or MTA), right from the get-go. And while you can certainly leverage some MFC classes in your MTA object, taking a dependency on a very large runtime like MFC to utilize CString and CFile is a bit excessive IMHO. And most developers are very unaware of the rules and restrictions around COM programming these days. To wit, I've probably forgotten 90% of them.
